# PostgreSQL double colon to Sequelize query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

```
select column_name::date, count(*) from table_name group by column_name::date
```

What is the equivalent of this SQL query in Sequelize?
I couldn't find what to do when there is "double colon" in PostgreSQL query.

Comment: It's a [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). In standard (ANSI) SQL it would be `cast(column_name as date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [a_horse_with_no_name comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426543/postgresql-double-colon-to-sequelize-query?noredirect=1#comment126248981_71426543) I decide to use;

```
sequelize.literal("cast(time_column_name as date)")
```

with the grouping section and the latest code take form;

```
ModelName.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.literal("cast(time_column_name as date)"), "time_column_name"],
  ],
  group: sequelize.literal("cast(time_column_name as date)"),
})
```

So, it gives two SQL query (because of findAndCountAll() function);

```
SELECT count(*) AS "count"
FROM "table_name"
GROUP BY cast(time_column_name as date);
```

AND

```
SELECT cast(time_column_name as date) AS "time_column_name"
FROM "table_name"
GROUP BY cast(time_column_name as date);
```